# Additional text found in json string after finishing deserializing object

Tags: c#, .net, json

This question have been asked a few times here but still there are some situations where it doesn't work.

I am working on reading json data using JSON.net and want to read the json data into dataset. I have following json data string ( It can be more complicated and can be nested to multiple levels)

```
[{"timestamp": 1383033661,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates" : {
  "AED": 3.673136,
  "AFN": 56.962675,
  "ALL": 101.792499,
  "AMD": 409.561999, 
  "YER": 215.109837,
  "ZAR": 9.851868,
  "ZMK": 5230.441665,
  "ZMW": 5.395017,
  "ZWL": 322.355006}}]
```

I am trying to read it into a data set using:

```
DataSet currency = (DataSet)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataSet)));
```

but it throws the exception:

```
"Additional text found in json string after finishing deserializing object"
```

**Note**:I tried converting single level json data into data table and it was successfully converted but again when I tried to convert it into dataset it failed with same above given exception.

Could anyone please give an insight of above exception and resolution for it ?

Comment: Why do you want to deserialise into a `DataSet`?

Comment: Actually above give code is just an example. Actually, I have to read json data and insert those data into different tables in database. Though I can do this as well using .net classes and mapping them with json data attributes. But still I am looking for the reason behind error when we try to convert the json to dataset.

Comment: A `DataSet` does not map to your json structure, namely because of `rates`

Comment: i think u dont need a DataSet..ur json message is valid..The string is getting deserialized after that mapping into DataSet is the issue. Any insights anyone?

Comment: So it seems that it is not possible to convert complex json data into dataset ?

Answer (score 2):

You need a structure similar to

```
public class Rate
{
    public string TimeSpan { get; set; }
    public string Base { get; set; }
    Dictionary<string, string> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

`rates` is another json object inside the json array.

```
const string json = @"{
  ""timestamp"": 1383033661,
  ""base"": ""USD"",
  ""rates"" : {
      ""AED"": 3.673136,
      ""AFN"": 56.962675,
      ""ALL"": 101.792499,
      ""AMD"": 409.561999, 
      ""YER"": 215.109837,
      ""ZAR"": 9.851868,
      ""ZMK"": 5230.441665,
      ""ZMW"": 5.395017,
      ""ZWL"": 322.355006
   }
}";

Rate currency = (Rate)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(Rate)));
```